# Checking for a single column name inside a for loop. How to stop repeating this check over and over once it has been satisfied?

Tags: python, pandas

This feels like something a 3 year old could figure out, I'm almost embarrassed to ask.

I want to print out the mean of each column in a dataframe.

But I don't want to print the mean if it's a certain column. So I check for this column and then skip it and move onto the next columns.

The problem is it does the check every single time. How can I stop the checking once the column has been skipped? I tried using `break`, `pass`, `continue` and a `while` loop. My while loops went on for infinity.

```
# for each column in the df
for col in d.columns:

    # skip column if it is column 1
    if col == 'column1':

        continue

    # print the mean of the other columns
    print(f'\nMean of {col}: {d[col].mean()}')
```

You can see in the output it works, I am getting the means, but I know it's still doing the check with every loop.

```
Mean of column2: 54.0

Mean of column3: 60.2

Mean of column4: 879.0
```

I know I can just remove `column1` before the loop but I'd like to see if I can skip this check once it has been satisfied.

Test dataframe for `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`:

```
dfdict = {'column1': {0: 'john', 1: 'mary', 2: 'partrick', 3: 'adam', 4: 'steve'},
 'column2': {0: 1, 1: 13, 2: 232, 3: 3, 4: 21},
 'column3': {0: 23, 1: 231, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 43},
 'column4': {0: 23, 1: 2, 2: 4332, 3: 34, 4: 4}}
```

Comment: you can directly iterate over `df.select_dtypes(np.number)` too if you want mean of all numeric columns

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop runs code for every element in the iterable. If there is a line that checks a condition within the `for` loop, it'll be checked for *every* iteration of that loop. Even if you store a variable that tells it whether or not to check, you'll be checking the value of that variable every time.

Your idea of removing the column before the loop resolves this issue because you won't need to check *any* columns.

Answer (score 1):

Don't enter the condition in the loop, you can filter the dataframe and use `DataFrame.mean` one time instead `Series.mean` N times. Then you use a loop.

```
for name, mean in df[df.columns.difference(['column1'])].mean().items():
    print(f'{name}, mean : {mean}')
```

---

```
column2, mean : 54.0
column3, mean : 60.2
column4, mean : 879.0
```

or

```
for name, mean in df.set_index(['column1']).mean().items():
    print(f'{name}, mean : {mean}')
```

keep in mind that this way you don't have to calculate the mean of N series but rather that you calculate the mean of the dataframe first (which is infinitely more efficient)

Answer (score 0):

Using Sets might help you if order is not important:

```
for col in set(d.columns)-set(['column1']):
    # print the mean of the other columns
    print(f'\nMean of {col}: {d[col].mean()}')
```

Comment: Yes, if order is important this shouldn't be used

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use d.columns[1:] to define the loop in the following way?

```
for col in d.columns[1:]:

     print(f'\nMean of {col}: {d[col].mean()}')
```

Comment: What if the column is in the middle rather than at the start?

Comment: In addition, this calculates the mean of N series and can calculate the mean of a DataFrame.